# 404 found with either get or post API spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, http-status-code-404

Creating the first full-stack website, starting with the database, then worked on API, and tried with get and post, but I kept getting a 404 response. running out of ideas to try

Looked at all sorts of questions on here, and they all seem to be having different issues, I'm positive it is packaged right, got all annotations, and it's probably something I have overlooked. Please help.

```
Main class
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.vault.safe.MyModel.UserModel", )
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.vault.safe.repositories.UserRepository")
public class DigitalVaultApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DigitalVaultApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

```
UserController
@RestController
@RequestMapping("users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

//*************************************************************************************
//Constructors, Getters, and Setters


    public UserController(UserService userService){
        super();
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    public UserService getUserService(){
        return userService;
    }

    public void setUserService(UserService userService){
        this.userService = userService;
    }

//*************************************************************************************
    @PostMapping("/add")
    public UserModel addUser(@RequestBody UserModel userModel){
        return userService.addUser(userModel);
    }

    @GetMapping("/getUserById/{userId}")
    public UserModel getUserById(@PathVariable Long userId){
        return userService.findById(userId);
    }
```

```
UserService
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;


    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        super();
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public UserRepository getUserRepository(){
        return userRepository;
    }

    public void setUserRepository(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

//***********************************************************************************************************
    public UserModel addUser(UserModel User){
        return userRepository.save(User);
    }

    public UserModel findById(Long userId) {
        Optional<UserModel> userOptional = userRepository.findById(userId);
        if (userOptional.isPresent()) {
            return userOptional.get();
        } else {
            throw new UserNotFoundException("User not found with ID: " + userId);
        }
    }
```

```
Model class is big, so just the contructor

 public UserModel(long id, String username, String email, String password, String password2, String firstName, String lastName, Integer age, String street1, String street2, String city, String state, String country, String zipcode, String phone) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.password2 = password2;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
        this.street1 = street1;
        this.street2 = street2;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.country = country;
        this.zipcode = zipcode;
        this.phone = phone;
    }
```

```
Repository
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserModel, Long>{
    List<UserModel> findUserById(Long id);
}
```

```
build.gradle
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway'
    implementation 'javax.persistence:persistence-api:1.0'
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa') {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-web'
    }
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-context'
    implementation 'com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-apache-client4:1.19.4'

    runtimeOnly 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
}
```

```
Application.Properties
server.port = 8080
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://localhost:8888

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/user_info?currentSchema=safetybox
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=Example
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.main.web-application-type=reactive
```

[image: snippet of error - whitelabel error, 404]

Comment: Could you share your application properties to see the servelet url?

Comment: Can you share the api details and application.properties file

Comment: Yes, my apologize, I have uploaded the app.prop

Answer (score 0):

Your `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.vault.safe.MyModel.UserModel", )` is wrong, causing the UserController not to be scanned.

Change it to something that includes the Controller, Service, Model, everything.

Either

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.vault.safe.MyModel.UserModel, com.vault.safe.foo.UserController, com.vault.safe.bar.Service" )
```

Or something more general, like:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.vault")
```

Comment: They could even remove the ComponentScan annotation assuming that the DigitalVaultApplication class is in the root package that contains all other spring beans that need to be scanned. The SpringBootApplication annotation should take care of the scanning of beans if that convention was followed.

Comment: So @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.vault") isn't working when I use clean build so I went with the first option, I also noticed that in my EnableJpaRepositories, Repositories had an error in it so after I fixed that and added the first ComponentScan I have reached new errors, saying "No property 'saveAll' found for type 'UserModel'" but I'm using JPA and not crud so that shouldn't matter, right?

Comment: So the change to ComponentScan fixed the 404. That’s the answer to your question. Please accept the answer. The saveAll issue is a new question. saveAll should be a method of the Repository class, not the Entity class.